# SSH command chain does not work when put in single line

Tags: bash, ssh

I have the following chain of commands which work perfectly well:

```
ssh Module
cd /MODULE_DIR/workspace/repository/
LATEST=`ls -tr *.snapshot | head -1`
mkdir fresh
cp ${LATEST} fresh
exit
```

I want to put this into a bash script:

```
ssh Module "cd /MODULE_DIR/workspace/repository/ && LATEST=`ls -tr *.snapshot | head -1` && mkdir fresh && cp \${LATEST} fresh"
```

But it outputs error:

```
ls: cannot access '*.snapshot': No such file or directory
cp: missing destination file operand after 'fresh'
Try 'cp --help' for more information.
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using single quotes instead of double-quotes on your SSH command.

Bash's [order of expansions](http://bashrules.blogspot.com/2006/04/bash-order-of-expansions.html) is going to try to expand those variables inside the double quotes based on the variable assignments on the computer you're running it on.

The variables in your command are likely blank locally; you can test this by adding an echo before the first quote and have the server echo back what command it's receiving.

Wrapping it in a single quote should make your local terminal not try to expand that variable and let the box you're connecting to handle it.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I've read about this on SO and this is why I escaped the dollar sign "\$" as someone suggested. Why wasn't it sufficient?

Comment: Second thing, I wish to develop this script to use it for different modules -- then I will have to pass and expand variable from outer scope anyway.

Comment: The backticks also need escaping if you stick with double quotes.